# Why does changing the x0 starting point cause optimization to not work?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have am trying to run an optimizer using scipy optimize. However why is it that if I change the x0 it will result in a sub optimal result.

The working line of code is if x0 is as follows: `x0=np.random.uniform(0.01, 50, len(returns))`. If I however change this line to something else such as `x0=np.random.uniform(0.01, 500, len(returns))` the output is no longer the most optimal despite the values still falling within the bounds set.

Below is the full code. Goal of the code is to find a list of numbers that will give the highest R-Squared when regressed against a given list of numbers.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from scipy.optimize import minimize, LinearConstraint

returns = {'Returns': [0.060458679, 0.061902247, 0.066269106, 0.080471895, 0.10595085, 0.086491221, 0.113036617, 0.137770782, 0.0777593, 0.070083323, 0.072254624]}
startvalues = {'Value': [14214252.35, 1401493.11, 14877567.11, 30553699.53, 11417231.53, 3698585.80, 4449329.62, 7111866.99, 4714928.31, 7196446.00, 22750284.22]}

returns = pd.DataFrame(returns)
startvalues = pd.DataFrame(startvalues)

def objective_function(values):
    returns['Risk Not Optimal'] = values
    returns['Log Risk Not Optimal'] = np.log(returns['Risk Not Optimal'])
    _, _, r_value, _, _ = stats.linregress(returns['Returns'], returns['Log Risk Not Optimal'])
    r_squared = r_value ** 2
    return -r_squared

def slope_constraint(values):
    returns['Risk Not Optimal'] = values
    slope, _, _, _, _ = stats.linregress(returns['Returns'], np.log(returns['Risk Not Optimal']))
    return slope - 14

# Define the bounds for the values of 'Risk Not Optimal'
bounds = [(0.01, 100000000)] * len(returns)  # Use the length of the DataFrame

# Define the slope constraint
slope_cons = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': slope_constraint}

# Perform optimization to maximize the negative R-squared
result = minimize(objective_function, x0=np.random.uniform(0.01, 50, len(returns)), constraints=slope_cons, bounds=bounds)

best_list = result.x
best_r_squared = -result.fun  # Convert back to positive

print("Best List:", best_list)
print("Best R-squared:", best_r_squared)
```

Ideally I was wanting to set x0 as `x0=startvalues`. However that didn't work and that's where I discovered the issue. I feel like I must be missing something fundamental as to how scipy optimise calculates the optimal value.

I have tried changing the constraints, and it seemed removing the slope constraint helped however that doesn't help me come to a solution. I was expecting the solution from both `x0=np.random.uniform(0.01, 50, len(returns))` and `x0=np.random.uniform(0.01, 50, len(returns))` to result in a similar optimized result however they are quite different. Is there potentially another optimization library I should be using?

Comment: Based on what you're saying, it sounds like the code is finding local minima when you use the initial guess with larger random (on average) values. For nonlinear, nonconvex optimization problems, this will always be an issue. Finding global minima from an arbitrary start point is very difficult. There are techniques, but it seems like you have it working for a smaller (on average) initial guess, so it's not necessary to try and implement other techniques. (Especially because those techniques can be annoying for high-dimensional problems.)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of reasons why this is a hard problem for an optimizer.

First, the objective being R^2 means that moving one variable closer to the desired solution can actually make the objective worse. What the solver needs to do if the slope is incorrect is to increase or decrease every value at once, and most of the solvers in scipy.optimize have a hard time doing that.

Second, there is a constraint on the slope of the regression, and that's another thing which is hard for most optimizers. Usually, what happens when they run into a constraint is that they make very small steps, which makes it less likely to converge. Again, this is a situation where in order to make progress without changing the slope, it might need to change multiple values at once.

For these reasons, it can be helpful to replace x0 with better initial guess. I found the following initial coefficents:

```
x0 = np.exp(returns['Returns'] * 14)
```

These are both perfectly correlated with your objective, and fulfill the slope constraint, no optimization required.